# Solr MLT Interestingterms return different terms than Lucene MoreLikeThis

Tags: java, solr, lucene, morelikethis

I am going to implement a searchcomponent for Solr to return document main keywords with using the more like this interesting terms. The main part of implemented component which uses mlt.retrieveInterestingTerms by lucene docID does not work for all of the documents. I mean for some of the documents solr interestingterms returns some useful terms as top tf-idf terms; however, the implemented method returns null! But for other documents both results (solr MLT interesting terms and the mlt.retrieveInterestingTerms(docId)) are the same!
Would you please help me through solving this issue?

```
public List<String> getKeywords(int docId) throws SyntaxError {
    String[] fields = new String[keywordSourceFields.size()];
    List<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();
    fields = keywordSourceFields.toArray(fields);
    mlt.setFieldNames(fields);
    mlt.setAnalyzer(indexSearcher.getSchema().getIndexAnalyzer());
    mlt.setMinTermFreq(minTermFreq);
    mlt.setMinDocFreq(minDocFreq);
    mlt.setMinWordLen(minWordLen);
    mlt.setMaxQueryTerms(maxNumKeywords);
    mlt.setMaxNumTokensParsed(maxTokensParsed);
    try {

      terms = Arrays.asList(mlt.retrieveInterestingTerms(docId));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    return terms;
  }
```

**Note:**

I did define `termVectors=true` for all the required fields that I am going to use for the purpose of generating interesting terms (fields array in the corresponding method)